# UIDeviceOrientationUnknown in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, opengl-es

I am trying to figure out what orientation the iphone has in the simulator and instead of giving it to me using the UIDevice orientation property I just get UIDeviceOrientationUnknown.

Does this property not work in the simulator?  What could be the possible reason for this happening?

I am using opengl es

Answer (score 12, accepted):

first of all, from the documentation about `orientation` property of UIDevice instance

> The value of this property always returns 0 unless orientation notifications have been enabled by calling beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications.

and yes, it will work only on the real device. but you can use, for example, [this](http://www.iphonearch.com/topic/6/iphone-accelerometer-simulator/) accelerometer simulator.

Comment: Sorry but no, it does not work only on the real device. I just loggued a landscape device orientation on the simulator and then a portrait one. Maybe it was not the case with previous SDK versions... (I'm on 3.1.3)

I guess we can use -[UIApplication statusBarOrientation] to determine the current interface orientation (except if we manually change the status bar orientation). And I'm not sure if this will work with a hidden status bar.

Comment: This works on the simulator, just not all the time. Use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation], as mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 46):

You can also use:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
```

which works even without calling `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications`.

Comment: best solution. I found the problem occurred in iOS 6 and new iPad. Your tips solved my problem. Big thanks

Comment: Glad iOS has this alternative!

Comment: @Chintan Patel Is this a bug ?